Build monorepo with pnpm
I created a Typescript monorepo with pnpm. The source code available is available here to reproduce the problem .
The monorepo contains a "shared" library and a "job" application. The "job" application is a simple cron task that calls a function from the "shared" library.
When I start the project in development, everything works fine. However, when I build and execute the transpiled TypeScript code, I encounter the following error:
Error: Cannot find module '@monorepo/shared/src/task'

Does anyone have any ideas what's wrong or has successfully deployed this kind of project?
